# Local notification is not working for android version 12 and above in flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

**Plugin used: awesome_notification**
[image]

This is my code for creating the local notification.
It is working fine up to android version 11, but after 12 version both the basic and schedule channel notification is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i also had same issue, this happens because notification are  not permitted by default , so show one dialog and route to enable setting page  with following  plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings/example
working for me